# Python urlparse.unparse_qsl?

Tags: python, urlparse

In Python's urlparse, you can use urlparse to parse the URL, and then parse_qsl to parse the query.

I want to *remove* a query (name, value) pair, and then reconstruct the URL.

There is a urlunparse method, but no unparse_qsl method.

What is the correct way to reconstruct the query from the qsl list?

Answer (score 2):

The function urllib.urlencode is appropriate.

Comment: Yes, that's the one that you should use.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> urlparse.parse_qsl('q=stackoverflow')
[('q', 'stackoverflow')]

>>> urllib.urlencode(urlparse.parse_qsl('q=stackoverflow'))
'q=stackoverflow'
```